# XSLT - multiple templates within HTML transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I can't find any solid, helpful answer to this online. For a class, I need to have an XML, XSD, XSL, HTML and CSS file to turn in. The XML and XSD are done and they're able to be validated, but I'm having trouble with the XSL/HTML. Basically I need to have 5 different templates within the same XSL -- one for each section I have in my XML. Here's the basic outline of my XML:

```
<duchovny>
    <filmography>
        ...
    </filmography>
    <vg>
        ...
    </vg>
    <music>
        ...
    </music>
    <books>
        ...
    <awards>
        ...
    </awards>
</duchovny>
```

This is what I have for my XSL -- it gives me an error when I try to display my XML in my browser ("Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed."):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
            <title>All About David Duchovny</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <header>
                    <h1>All About David Duchovny</h1>
                    <div id="navigation">
                        <nav>
                            <a href="#filmography">filmography</a> | 
                            <a href="#vg">video games</a> | 
                            <a href="#music">music</a> | 
                            <a href="#bookd">books</a> | 
                            <a href="#awards">awards</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="filmography">
                <section>
                    <div id="filmography" a href="#filmography">
                        <h2>Filmography</h2>
                        <h3>Movies</h3>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//film">
                            <p><xsl:value-of select="film/info1/@title"/></p>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </xsl:template>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can't figure out why exactly this doesn't work. It works when I put  just after the output call, but then the section where I try to display the titles of the films doesn't appear (because I need to close the HTML element before that section, I imagine). I can't figure out how to apply multiple templates and get them all to show up.

Alternatively (though equally non-functioning), I have this code attempting to use apply-template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
                <title>All About David Duchovny</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <header>
                    <h1>All About David Duchovny</h1>
                    <div id="navigation">
                        <nav>
                            <a href="#filmography">filmography</a> | 
                            <a href="#vg">video games</a> | 
                            <a href="#music">music</a> | 
                            <a href="#bookd">books</a> | 
                            <a href="#awards">awards</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <section>
                    <xsl:apply-template match="filmography" mode="filmography"/>
                </section>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="filmography">
        <div id="filmography" a href="#filmography">
            <h2>Filmography</h2>
            <h3>Movies</h3>
            <xsl:for-each select="//film">
                <p><xsl:value-of select="film/info1/@title"/></p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I fixed the "<div id="filmography" a href="#filmography">" to remove the unnecessary 'a,' so please ignore that!

Comment: Good Catch !!!! you can normally check the document is well formed by opening in web browser for such as error.

Comment: There's a meta-problem here. Your first attempt is completely wrong (xsl:template can't appear except as a child of xsl:stylesheet). Now (a) this suggests you were guessing: you wrote some code without first doing enough reading to understand the concepts of the language, and (b) you didn't get any decent diagnostics because you're trying to run the code in the browser without first creating the right development environment to ensure you get good feedback on your mistakes. In short: you jumped in at the deep end without taking any swimming lessons or finding out the depth of the pool.

Comment: I find your comment to be pretty rude in all honesty. This was my second attempt at writing an XSLT (my first was successful) as the project guidelines were only given to us after I had finished all my work. I clearly didn't understand what the problem was, and your comment is nowhere near helpful. I've paid attention in class and I've followed the lessons well; this just isn't something that we spent an enormous amount of time on. Thanks to the answer someone shared here, I was able to work it out and complete my project, but I needed to let you know that your judgement is rude and unwanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line...

```
<xsl:apply-template match="filmography" mode="filmography"/>
```

The problems are as follows:

1. It should be `xsl:apply-templates`.
2. `match` is not a valid attibute on `xsl:apply-templates`. You should use `select`
3. You are in a template matching `\` which is the document node. This is the parent of the `duchovny` node, so trying to select `filmography` won't find anything. Change the template match to `\duchovny` instead (or just `\*`)
4. You also don't need `mode` here (although `mode` is valid, it is just that you don't really need to use it in this case)

So, it should be `<xsl:apply-templates select="filmography" />` but you mention about wanting multiple templates, presumably to match `vg` and `award`, etc. In this case, just do this, as this will select all child nodes of `duchovny` and find the relevant matching node for them

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
                <title>All About David Duchovny</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <header>
                    <h1>All About David Duchovny</h1>
                    <div id="navigation">
                        <nav>
                            <a href="#filmography">filmography</a> | 
                            <a href="#vg">video games</a> | 
                            <a href="#music">music</a> | 
                            <a href="#bookd">books</a> | 
                            <a href="#awards">awards</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <section>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </section>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="filmography">
        <a name="filmography" />
        <div id="filmography">
            <h2>Filmography</h2>
            <h3>Movies</h3>
            <xsl:for-each select="//film">
                <p><xsl:value-of select="film/info1/@title"/></p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="vg">
        <h2>vg goes here</h2>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working and completed the project in the way I wanted to. It's a very basic page due to a) lack of time and b) lack of skills with CSS, but it has all the necessary information. Your answer is really appreciated